# Maps API V2 Versions

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm having a fit trying to get a V2 map to work in a ViewPager.  When I go to

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/releases#august_2013

I see that in August 2013 (this month) they improved behavior of V2 Maps in a ViewPager.

(it would be soooooo nice if they would put version numbers on that page)

If I open up my SDK manager I see that I have Google Play Services version 10 installed.

How do I know that this is the August version with the ViewPager fixes.

Thanks, Gary

Answer (score 0):

> How do I know that this is the August version with the ViewPager fixes.

If there are no updates available for it, you have the latest version.

In this case, I can confirm that R10 is the August version.